# How is Obi-wan Kenobi aware of those facts?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi, star-wars-rebels

In the latest Star Wars Rebels episode *Twin suns*, we hear Obi-Wan say:

> “You're in the wrong place, Ezra Bridger.”

Moreover, throughout the conversation, we learn that

> Obi-Wan knows Maul is after him, and is somewhat linked to Ezra

How did Obi-Wan ever learn about this name and this fact? As far as I know he is isolated on Tatooine and has no external contact with anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's never stated explicitly in the episode, we can make some plausible guesses:

**Bail Organa**: Bail is definitely aware of and able to contact Kenobi. The way he referred to him in Rogue One, though, suggests they are not in regular contact.

**Yoda**: Yoda has been in recent, direct contact with Ezra through the Force; he and Yoda have also been training with Qui-Gon. There's no reason to believe that they could not be in contact with one another.

**The Grapevine**: Kenobi isn't totally isolated on Tatooine; certainly he knows enough to know that Mos Eisley is a wretched hive of scum and villainy, and he's sufficiently in touch with the world that he can rejoin it with ease. Ezra hasn't exactly been keeping a low profile - there's every chance that Kenobi could have heard Ezra's broadcast, or at least have heard about it.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to assume that Kenobi and Yoda are in contact while in their exiles. Why would Kenobi send Luke to a planet with such a dark presence if he is not absolutely sure Yoda is still there to take care of him.

Comment: I do not think Organa is in contact with Kenobi. "Ahsoka" (book) mentions that contacting Kenobi was not an option as it would put Luke and Leia at risk of being discovered by the Empire/Sith. I do believe that Yoda and Kenobi are in contact (force chat?) and that Obi-wan has sources for information that he can access on Tatooine (cantina Chatter, police scanner, old contacts from Jedi days).

Answer (score -1):

Yoda is almost 900 years old. Is Jedi wise and powerful.  He knows much of what goes on that is connected to the force.  Especially with so many less Jedi these days, he can sense Ezra and his goings on.  And is in force communication with Obi to relay such info

Comment: Does this have any canon background?